# Check if user has an account on WordPress site

Tags: android, wordpress, authentication

I'm working on a mobile app specifically for students at my university. Our school's web portal uses WordPress (or at least the login page is /wp-login.php).

Is there a way to send the user's browser to the login page and then send them back to the app with a confirmation that they were able to sign in? Or even better, include their username? I've tried a bunch of different Google searches, but most of what I've found requires installing/configuring plugins in the WordPress install, but that's not an option, since I'm just a student.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the school's site hosted at WordPress.com or they have their own hosting provider?

Comment: @Panayotis It is hosted on their own servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since the site is not hosted at WordPress.com, you will have to implement your own API Endpoint for your Single Sign-On procedure.

But first contact the site's admin or developer/s and find out if they have already implemented such a mechanism.

If they haven't [you can see here](http://coderrr.com/create-an-api-endpoint-in-wordpress/) how to create an API Endpoint in WordPress, that your mobile application will use to authenticate users.

You can find [more information here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58906/create-api-for-single-sign-on-with-3rd-party-site).

If your university's site does not support the functionality and they are not willing to implement it, I 'm afraid that you cannot do anything...